# jQuery context menu - finding what element triggered it off

Tags: jquery, html, css, contextmenu

I am trying to write a context menu option for a page of mine.
Basically a div is right-clicked, an options menu pops up which can be used to perform tasks.

My problem is trying to find the original element which triggered everything (ie the div that was right-clicked).

My jQuery code is more or lesS:

```
//this is what displays the context menu
$('.outfeedPosition').bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
    $('#contextMenu').css({
        top: e.pageY + 'px',
        left: e.pageX + 'px'
    }).show();

    //'this' is the element which was clicked by the user.
    alert($(this).attr('id'));

    return false;
});



//this is the contextMenu's button handler.
$('#ctxDelete').click(function () {
    alert('delete was clicked, but i dont know by which element - so I dont know which one to delete');
});


<div id="contextMenu">
    <ul>
        <li><a id="ctxInsert" href="#">Insert</a></li>
        <li><a id="ctxEdit" href="#">Edit</a></li>
        <li><a id="ctxDelete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

--
So - I can see what element created the event when the initial right-click happens.
But not when the menu item is clicked.

I was working on fumbling something together by writing the element out to a hidden textbox when it is right-clicked, then reading it when one of the options is clicked, then removing it when the menu closes.
Doesn't seem like the ideal approach though - and I feel like i'm missing something basic.

Hope you see what I am trying to do.
I can post a more complete example on request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could consider using the jQuery [data storage](http://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/data-storage/) methods.

In your context menu code you can put:

```
$('.outfeedPosition').bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
    $('#contextMenu').css({
        top: e.pageY + 'px',
        left: e.pageX + 'px'
    }).show();

    //Store the item that was clicked 
    $("#contextMenu").data('originalElement', this);

    return false;
});
```

Then when you want to reference the element that initiated the click, you can just do this:

```
$('#ctxDelete').click(function () {
    var originalElement = $("#contextMenu").data('originalElement');
    alert('delete was clicked by ' + originalElement.id );
});
```

And put `originalElement` in the jQuery function `$()` to access the jQuery goodness. It doesn't matter where you put the data, since any DOM element can have data associated to it. You can store anything - in the example code above, I store the `HTMLElement` raw (not jQueryified) but you can store that too if you want.

See here for a little example: http://www.jsfiddle.net/jonathon/sTJ6M/

Comment: Two remarks: 1. You are using the selector engine to find the #contextMenu element multiple times. It would be reasonable to cache that jQuery object: `var $contextMenu = $("#contextMenu");` 2. It might be a good idea to guard against `originalElement` being undefined, in which case `originalElement.id` would throw an error.

Comment: Cheers Šime. I agree with your points but I wasn't too concerned with refactoring. I was just slotting into the OP's code and making it clear how to use the data methods. In this instance, rather than cache the object, you can just benefit from chaining and not require the extra variable :)

Comment: Thanks Jonathon, thats just what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I add a hidden field and then find it based on the click, like this:

```
<div class="myItem">
    <div id="contextMenu">
        <ul>
            <li><a id="ctxInsert" href="#">Insert</a></li>
            <li><a id="ctxEdit" href="#">Edit</a></li>
            <li><a id="ctxDelete" href="#">Delete</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" class="myID" value="1">
</div>
```

then with JQuery

```
$('#ctxDelete').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).closest('.myItem').find('.myID').val();   
    alert('delete was clicked, by element with ID = ' + id);
});
```

Comment: You might want to look at the data storage methods - it saves having to create hidden input type for things like this (and lets you save any object, not just strings): http://api.jquery.com/category/miscellaneous/data-storage/

Comment: looks cool, but the problem is.. it fires when a left click is performed.. +1 though :)

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little late to the party here but I found that when the context menu is generated the active item gets the 'context-menu-active' class added to it. This may only be in more recent versions. I'm using context menu 1.6.6.

Simply add:

```
var originalElement = $('.context-menu-active');
```

to the context menu handler. Here it is combined with the example code.

```
$(function(e){
    $.contextMenu({
        selector: '.context-menu-one',
        callback: function(key, options) {
            var originalElement = $('.context-menu-active');
            var m = "clicked: " + originalElement[0].innerHTML;
            window.console && console.log(m);
        },
        items: {
            "edit": {name: "Edit"},
            "cut": {name: "Cut"},
            "copy": {name: "Copy"},
            "paste": {name: "Paste"},
            "delete": {name: "Delete"},
            "sep1": "---------",
            "quit": {name: "Quit"}
        }
    });

    $('.context-menu-one').on('click', function(e){
       console.log('clicked', this);
    })
});
```