# jQuery UI Cannot Find 'contextmenu' right-click Event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, events, contextmenu, jquery-ui-dialog

so I'm using the following context menu:

```
(function($) {
$.fn.setUpContextMenu = function() {
    $(this).dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
        resizable: false,
        width: 'auto',
        height: 'auto',
        minHeight: 'auto',
        minWidth: 'auto'
    });

    return $(this);
};

$.fn.openContextMenu = function(jsEvent) {
    var menu = $(this);
    menu.css('padding', 0);

    menu.dialog('option', 'position', [jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY]);
    menu.unbind('dialogopen');
    menu.bind('dialogopen', function(event, ui) {
        $('.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide();
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').unbind('click');
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').css('opacity', 0);
        $('.ui-widget-overlay').click(function() {
            menu.dialog('close');
        });
    });
    menu.dialog('open');

    return menu;
};
```

})(jQuery);

I use it like so:

```
$('#context-menu a').css('display', 'block').button();
        $('#context-menu').setUpContextMenu();
        $(document).bind('contextmenu', function(e) {
            $('#context-menu').openContextMenu(e);
            return false;
        });
```

The context menu looks like this:

```
<!--RIGHT-CLICK MENU MARKUP!--> 
<div id="context-menu">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="option1">Option 1</a>
    <a href="javascript: alert($(this).attr('href'));">Option 2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="option3">Option 3</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="option4">Option 4</a>
</div>
```

Here's my problem. I'm trying to figure out how to capture the right click event, that way I can determine from what element the event was fired. I know that if I have to I can just add a new data value to $('#context-menu') that holds the event, but that seems very roundabout and not very elegant at all. There has to be a better way to get the original event.

Thanks for any help, I appreciate it :)

**EDIT: ** To clarify, I want to figure out how to refer to the right click event from inside the  tags inside the actual context menu markup. I execute some javascript when they are clicked, how do I refer to the event in order to figure out which element fired it?

Comment: TONY WHY'D YOU DELETE YOUR COMMENT! :(

Anyways, I don't think you understood what I was asking. I'll try to clarify. I want to be able to access the original right-click event from the links in the context menu. I want to be able to refer to them from within it. How do I do this?

Comment: laugh :P yeah i read your title and looked at it and noticed it wasnt exactly what you were looking for so I added a right click example also hehe. Though I may still be unsure of what you asked if that is not correct. Sorry :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand what you want now, which seeing your site helped me understand (I think?) I haven't created the code here but I will give you the logic behind it.

OnRightClick(of the form element) - Store $(this)(the form element) as a variable in your javascript, the function that loads when your page does.

SelectMenuItem - When you select your menu item you can then reference the variable that contains your triggered element. Once you are finished with the element clear the variable.

You may also want to clear it when the context menu is closed without a selection.

Better Yet, jQuery UI has datastorage check this post out for some helpful code :)

[jQuery context menu - finding what element triggered it off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430015/jquery-context-menu-finding-what-element-triggered-it-off)

Comment: I think you might still be confused, but no worries, I appreciate all the help I can get. So, the events are firing perfectly fine. The problem is, lets say I right click and open the context menu. How do I know which DOM element fired it? I'm making a [form builder](http://caidenhome.com/jQuery_Form_Builder/builder.html), and when I right click, I want to know which element fired the event. This way, I can act directly on that element.

Comment: You should include the form builder link in your question I believe it helped me understand what you are looking for, before I post anything else I just want to verify. I drop a panel on the form, I right-click and now I have your context menu. When I click an Item in the menu, you are trying to figure out how to detect which element (the Panel) that called the initial context menu so you can than modify that element. Right now all you are getting is the context menu. Correct? I will update my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much, this is exactly what I was looking for. I knew I could store the event in a variable, but it just didn't seem as elegant as I thought. With jquery UI datastorage things should run much more smoothly.