# jQuery contextmenu know what triggered

Tags: jquery, contextmenu

I'm currently using this contextmenu plugin:
http://medialize.github.io/jQuery-contextMenu

Now I've got a list on which I've bound a menu.
The menu itself is working.

But I need to know what element in the list has triggered the contextMenu, when I click on an item in the list.
As far as I can see right now, I only can see what item in the contextMenu is clicked, but not which item has triggered the contextMenu.

Does someone knows how to do this? Maybe I need another contextMenu plugin?

The code that binds the menu to the list:

```
$.contextMenu({
    selector: '#productsWindow li a',
    items: $.contextMenu.fromMenu($('#productRightclickOnProductMenu'))
});
```

[Link to jsFidle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4eqqh4b/)

Comment: Hi mam , please include jsFiddle

Comment: You can bind an event for mouse down for the items and check if its the right mouse button.
$('#productsWindow li a').mousedown(function(e){ 
    if( e.button == 2 ) { 
      alert('Right mouse button!'); 
      return false; 
    } 
    return true; 
  });

Comment: jsFiddle included with a stripped-down version of the code.

Comment: That's indeed a good idea. The problem is that there will be a lot of choises (not only delete like in the Fiddle), so in that case I would need to save the choise in een global variable en check it in that right click event.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430015/jquery-context-menu-finding-what-element-triggered-it-off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this http://jsfiddle.net/r4eqqh4b/3/
I had to move html menu to js menu initialization code.
In the callback function option parameter has the original element that triggered the context menu.

JS Code

```
$.contextMenu({
      selector:  '#productsWindow li a',
      callback: function (key, options) 
                {
                  console.log($(options.$trigger).text());
                },
        items: {
                "Delete": { name: "Delete" },
                }
            });
```

HTML Code

```
<ul id="productsWindow">
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 0px;">C0002 - Dummy CPU</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 0px;">R0001 - Kingston DDR18</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 0px;">C0005 - lkjlkj</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 0px;" class="">arno002 - mlkj</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-left: 0px;">comp0001 - Een lege computer</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The initialization did the trick. I was already trying with the callback, but it didn't work. Thank you!